# How do I remove a specific pygame.draw on click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm learning pygame by making some basic games, in the following one I'm trying to make a memory puzzle where there are 4 shapes with 4 colours hidden behind black cards/covers, user has to click on one black card/covers to reveal the shape behind it and has to match it with other shape with the same colour by guessing.

The code I've came with so far for those cards

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
import random

window_wth = 720
window_hgt = 360
window_resolution = window_wth, window_hgt

fps = 15

card_wth = 72
card_hgt = 92
gap_x = 77
gap_y = 97

c1 = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))
c2 = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))
c3 = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))
c4 = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))

bkg_colour = (30, 30, 30)
pg.display.set_caption("Game")
main_display = pg.display.set_mode(window_resolution)
pos_x = int((window_wth % gap_x) / 2)
pos_y = int((window_hgt % gap_y) / 2)


def list_draw_rct(tt_pos_x, tt_pos_y):
    rect_areas1 = []
    for x in range(tt_pos_x, window_wth - gap_x, gap_x):
        for y in range(tt_pos_y, window_hgt - gap_y, gap_y):
            colour = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))
            rect_area1 = pg.Rect(x, y, card_wth, card_hgt)
            rect_areas1.append(rect_area1)
    # print(rect_areas1)
    return rect_areas1


def main():
    global fps_clock, main_display
    fps_clock = pg.time.Clock()

    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():

            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key == pg.K_s:
                for i in range(len(list_draw_rct(pos_x, pos_y))):
                    colour = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))
                    pg.draw.rect(main_display, colour, list_draw_rct(pos_x, pos_y)[i], 5)
                    pg.display.update(list_draw_rct(pos_x, pos_y)[:5] + list_draw_rct(pos_x,pos_y)[(6):])
                    fps_clock.tick(fps)


            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here I've hard coded removing 5th element

```
if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key == pg.K_s:
                for i in range(len(list_draw_rct(pos_x, pos_y))):
                    colour = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))
                    pg.draw.rect(main_display, colour, list_draw_rct(pos_x, pos_y)[i], 5)
                    pg.display.update(list_draw_rct(pos_x, pos_y)[:5] + list_draw_rct(pos_x,pos_y)[(6):])
                    fps_clock.tick(fps)
```

But I don't know how to do that with user input.

Comment: Try to think of a way to do it yourself, using google to answer any general questions. Then, if you run into any issues, you can ask here a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a card class and then given each card a rect and colour at creation. Then I check for mouse button press and then get the mouse pos and do a rect.collidepoint(pos) check, and delete the card:

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
import random

window_wth = 720
window_hgt = 360
window_resolution = window_wth, window_hgt

fps = 15

card_wth = 72
card_hgt = 92
gap_x = 77
gap_y = 97

c1 = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))
c2 = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))
c3 = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))
c4 = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))

bkg_colour = (30, 30, 30)
pg.display.set_caption("Game")
main_display = pg.display.set_mode(window_resolution)
background = pg.Surface(window_resolution)

pos_x = int((window_wth % gap_x) / 2)
pos_y = int((window_hgt % gap_y) / 2)

global cards

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, colour):
        super(Card, self).__init__()

        self.colour = colour
        self.xpos = xpos
        self.ypos = ypos
        self.width = 72
        self.height = 92
        self.rect = pg.Rect((xpos, ypos, self.width, self.height))

def make_cards(tt_pos_x, tt_pos_y):
    global cards
    cards = []
    for x in range(tt_pos_x, window_wth - gap_x, gap_x):
        for y in range(tt_pos_y, window_hgt - gap_y, gap_y):
            colour = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255))
            card = Card(x, y, colour)
            cards.append(card)
    return cards

def main():
    global fps_clock, main_display, cards
    fps_clock = pg.time.Clock()

    while True:


        if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            print "mouse button pressed"
            pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            for card in cards:
                if card.rect.collidepoint(pos):
                    cards.remove(card)

        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        fps_clock.tick(fps)
        update()

def update():
    global cards
    background.fill((0,0,0))
    for card in cards:
        pg.draw.rect(background, card.colour, card.rect, 5)

    main_display.blit(background, (0,0))
    pg.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global cards
    cards = make_cards(pos_x, pos_y)
    pg.display.update()
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, that works flawlessly! Seems like I was thinking way too much inside the box, never thought of drawing the entire thing on pg.Surface and blit~ing background on main_display without that clicked element.